# unable to create bean error with name 'entityManagerFactory' bean

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, aspectj, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm using

1. `JDK 1.8`
2. `MySQL` 8.0.31
3. `Spring` version 5.3.27
4. `Aspectj` version 1.8.10
5. `log4j-api(core, web)` version 2.17.1

updating the log trace

```
May 17, 2023 12:16:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
May 17, 2023 12:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
May 17, 2023 12:16:22 PM com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.JSONRPCBridge registerLocalArgResolver
INFO: registered local arg resolver com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.HttpServletRequestArgResolver for local class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest with context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
May 17, 2023 12:16:22 PM com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.JSONRPCBridge registerLocalArgResolver
INFO: registered local arg resolver com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.HttpSessionArgResolver for local class javax.servlet.http.HttpSession with context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
May 17, 2023 12:16:22 PM com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.JSONRPCBridge registerLocalArgResolver
INFO: registered local arg resolver com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.JSONRPCBridgeServletArgResolver for local class com.metaparadigm.jsonrpc.JSONRPCBridge with context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.demoweb.web.util.demoWebContextListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/demoweb-backend/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.demoweb.web.util.demoWebContextListener.contextInitialized(demoWebContextListener.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.injectClassLoaderDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate;)V
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.generateHcannReflectionManager(BootstrapContextImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.<init>(BootstrapContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at com.demoweb.backend.util.demoLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(demoLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 53 more

May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of deployment descriptor [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml] has finished in [22,712] ms
May 17, 2023 12:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\webapps\abc.war]
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**applicationcontext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
    
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/demoweb-backend.properties" />
    
    
    <util:properties id="demoProperties" location="file:///${catalina.home}/conf/demo.properties"/>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="com.demoweb.backend.util.demoLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="demowebDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="demoweb" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${demoweb.database.generateddl}" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${demoweb.database.platform}" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
      
    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"  proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.demoweb.backend.repository" />
    
</beans>
```

i'm not sure whats wrong with my bean i'm currentely upgrading my application which is causing this error. If some can point me in correct direction really appriciate the help.

Removing the hibernate conflitcs resolved the " No persistence unit with name" but its still can't create bean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No Persistence Unit Found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985378/no-persistence-unit-found-error)

Comment: its partially resolved the issue but it still can't create the bean

Comment: Please check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498590/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-servletcontext-r

Comment: nope still the same error updated the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api to hibernate-jpa-2.1-api

Comment: Can you update with the complete log?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it is too much code to post here, even though it is minimal, feel free to link to a GitHub reprository reproducing your problem. Thank you.